# "Member is private" although I don't access it from outside, when using trailing return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, functional-programming, metaprogramming

How can I fix the following problem?

I'm writing some functional library which defines the following functions which are relevant for this question:

- `call(f,arg)`: Calls a function with an argument. Just a wrapper I need for some situations.
- `comp(f1,f2)`: Returns a composition of two functions. Returns a helper functor representing the composition of the two functions.

The implementation looks like the following (simplified versions which still demonstrate the problem):

```
// Call f with one argument
template <class Fn, class Arg>
auto call(const Fn &f, const Arg & arg) -> decltype(f(arg)) {
    return f(arg);
}

// Helper functor for the function below
template<class Fn1, class Fn2>
class CompFn {
    Fn1 a;
    Fn2 b;

public:
    CompFn(const Fn1 &f1, const Fn2 &f2) : a(f1), b(f2) {}

    template<class Arg> inline
    auto operator()(const Arg & arg) const -> decltype(call(b, call(a, arg))) {
        return call(b, call(a, arg));
    }
};

/** Composition of f1 and f2 (f2 after f1). */
template<class Fn1, class Fn2>
CompFn<Fn1,Fn2> comp(const Fn1 &f1, const Fn2 &f2) {
    return CompFn<Fn1,Fn2>(f1, f2);
}
```

The following code is used as a simple test:

```
// Example: Take the length of the string and compare it against zero.
std::function<int(std::string)> stringLength = [](std::string s) { return s.size(); };
std::function<bool(int)> greaterZero = [](int x) { return x > 0; };
auto stringNotEmpty = comp(stringLength, greaterZero);

std::string testInput1 = "foo";
std::string testInput2 = "";
```

Until here, everything works fine. Calling `comp` itself doesn't seem to be a problem. Calling the resulting function directly is also OK. But calling the composition via `call` introduces an infinity number of compilation errors (yaaay, new record!):

```
assert(call(stringNotEmpty,testInput1) == true);    // line 44
assert(call(stringNotEmpty,testInput2) == false);
```

The compilation output (gcc 4.7, full output see ideone links below):

```
prog.cpp:16:9: error: ‘std::function<bool(int)> CompFn<std::function<int(std::basic_string<char>)>, std::function<bool(int)> >::b’ is private
prog.cpp:44:5: error: within this context
prog.cpp:15:9: error: ‘std::function<int(std::basic_string<char>)> CompFn<std::function<int(std::basic_string<char>)>, std::function<bool(int)> >::a’ is private
prog.cpp:44:5: error: within this context
prog.cpp:22:10: error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum) substituting ‘template<class Fn, class Arg> decltype (f(arg)) call(const Fn&, const Arg&) [with Fn = std::function<int(std::basic_string<char>)>; Arg = std::basic_string<char>]’
prog.cpp:22:10:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Arg> decltype (call(((const CompFn*)this)->CompFn<Fn1, Fn2>::b, call(((const CompFn*)this)->CompFn<Fn1, Fn2>::a, arg))) CompFn::operator()(const Arg&) const [with Arg = Arg; Fn1 = std::function<int(std::basic_string<char>)>; Fn2 = std::function<bool(int)>] [with Arg = std::basic_string<char>]’
prog.cpp:8:6:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Fn, class Arg> decltype (f(arg)) call(const Fn&, const Arg&) [with Fn = std::function<int(std::basic_string<char>)>; Arg = std::basic_string<char>]’
prog.cpp:22:10:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Arg> decltype (call(((const CompFn*)this)->CompFn<Fn1, Fn2>::b, call(((const CompFn*)this)->CompFn<Fn1, Fn2>::a, arg))) CompFn::operator()(const Arg&) const [with Arg = Arg; Fn1 = std::function<int(std::basic_string<char>)>; Fn2 = std::function<bool(int)>] [with Arg = std::basic_string<char>]’
prog.cpp:8:6:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Fn, class Arg> decltype (f(arg)) call(const Fn&, const Arg&) [with Fn = std::function<int(std::basic_string<char>)>; Arg = std::basic_string<char>]’
prog.cpp:22:10:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Arg> decltype (call(((const CompFn*)this)->CompFn<Fn1, Fn2>::b, call(((const CompFn*)this)->CompFn<Fn1, Fn2>::a, arg))) CompFn::operator()(const Arg&) const [with Arg = Arg; Fn1 = std::function<int(std::basic_string<char>)>; Fn2 = std::function<bool(int)>] [with Arg = std::basic_string<char>]’
prog.cpp:8:6:   [ skipping 890 instantiation contexts ]
[ ...continues endlessly... ]
```

When converting the composition to a `std::function`, it's also perfectly fine. But this will not allow to use polymorphic functors with my `comp` function, at least I don't see an option.

One "fix" is to **not use trailing return type with decltype** for the `Comp::operator()`, but fixing the return type to `bool` (specialized for this single test scenario).

All four mentioned test cases summarized:

- [Test1](http://ideone.com/0URRy3) -- Call the composition directly --> OK
- [Test2](http://ideone.com/rmK4n0) -- Call the composition using `call` **--> Error**
- [Test3](http://ideone.com/Zgz1A9) -- Cast the composition to std::function, then call using `call` --> OK
- [Test4](http://ideone.com/CcrC9V) -- Call the composition using `call`. Fixed return type of `Comp::operator()` to `bool` --> OK

**My goal** is to make `call` a "seemless" wrapper to call any type of function: Functors, function pointers, member function pointers, member variable pointers, etc..., and also a composition using `comp`. I have a bunch of overloads for them but I don't want to introduce an overload for `Comp<Fn1,Fn2>` since `Fn1` or `Fn2` can again be any type of function, it seems to be a "recursive problem".

Comment: What if you substituted some expression of Fn1 for a, Fn2 for b?  Not totally encapsulated, but still using the trailing return type without mentioning private members.

Comment: Aah, you mean `std::declval<Fn1>()` instead of `a` in the trailing return type expression? Let me try this. Excellent idea.

Comment: @ScottJones You're my hero of the day. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Very good catch! However, it seems to be a compiler bug, since decltype should only "calculate" the type of an expression without taking into account some access specifiers (I guess)). Clang seems to compile it, according to Xeo's answer.

Comment: @leemes: The access specifiers shouldn't make problems in any case, since you're in a member function of `CompFn`.

Comment: @Xeo Yeah I also guessed that. But it *does* (seems to be a compiler bug). Replacing it like I said makes my code compile under gcc 4.7.

Comment: @leemes: gcc 4.8.1 compiles the code fine, so you might want to upgrade.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks for reporting, so I guess this makes filing a bug report unnecessary. Yeah, I'll upgrade very soon, but all my team members would have to do this too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try substituting an expression of Fn1 for a, Fn2 for b to avoid mentioning private members.  I tried this in VC++, but got a different error:

```
template<class Arg> inline
auto operator()(const Arg & arg) const -> decltype(call(Fn1(), call(Fn2(), arg))) {
    return call(b, call(a, arg));
}
```

Comment: As already discussed in the comments, this fixed the compilation error. The infinity number of follow-up errors didn't remove yet. I needed to apply the same fix to `call` which, as you can see, also uses trailing return type. Replacing `f` with `std::declval<Fn>()` fixed it though.

Comment: But you should write `std::declval<T>()` instead of `T()`, since it might not have a default constructor.

Comment: @leemes Right - I was just hacking in an expression to remove a and b

Answer (score 6):

Clang compiles your failing test case just fine, and I can't see any error with it, so I think this is a GCC bug. Please file a bug-report with a minimal repro (no includes) if you can.

Note: For `call`, there's already something *like* it in the standard - `INVOKE`, which is not a macro, but a concept, so to speak. It's used by `std::bind`, `std::function` and other things, one of which is `std::reference_wrapper`. This means that you can do `std::ref(fun)(args...)` to achieve the same as `call`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint about `INVOKE`. I'll give it a try (I can make my `call` just a wrapper around it, I guess.) Should make my code cleaner. And thanks for trying Clang.